# force images inside bootstrap fixed footer to align horizontally on phone resolution

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make the social images to be horizontally on phones , it works fine on higher resolutions , but when I switch to phone resolution the images align vertically and extend the footer over the content, here how the code looks like :

```
<!-- Footer -->
<footer>
    <nav id="top-nav" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom custom-footer">
        <div class="container ">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img id="logo-fot" alt="BeBandSM" src="img/logo-fot.png">
                </a>
            </div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#"><img class="social-media-img" src="img/facebook.png" alt=""></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img class="social-media-img" src="img/google_plus.png" alt=""></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img class="social-media-img" src="img/twitter.png" alt=""></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img class="social-media-img" src="img/youtube.png" alt=""></a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
.custom-footer{
    background-color: #000000;
}


.social-media-img {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;

}
```

result:
High Res.
[image]

Phone Res.

[image]

how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the bootstrap-floating css-class "pull-left" to every list-element should do the trick, e.g.:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="pull-left"><a href="#"><img class="social-media-img" src="img/facebook.png" alt=""></a></li>
    <li class="pull-left"><a href="#"><img class="social-media-img" src="img/google_plus.png" alt=""></a></li>
    <li class="pull-left"><a href="#"><img class="social-media-img" src="img/twitter.png" alt=""></a></li>
    <li class="pull-left"><a href="#"><img class="social-media-img" src="img/youtube.png" alt=""></a></li>
</ul>
```